# Fetch Group by values of the second column

Tags: php, pdo

The following code teaches me how to group result by the first column. But I don't know how to do it with the second column. Please explain and give me some example that make me clearly understand. Thank you so much. (Sorry about my English)

```
$insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO fruit(name, colour) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert->execute(array('apple', 'green'));
$insert->execute(array('pear', 'yellow'));

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Group values by the first column */
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));
```

**And the most important is whether I can group base on the name of table field or not.** (In this case I don't care the index of the column name, I just know the field name). Thanks

Comment: *"And the most important is whether I can group base on the name of table field or not."* - Then use MySQL's GROUP BY clause http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Comment: If you want to be able to group the result set by the field name, then you're **much** better of learning a bit more about what MySQL can do: `GROUP BY` being the better tool for the job here

Comment: When I use GROUP BY. I don't have my desire result.

Comment: Then use ORDER BY - Show us a sample output of what you want.

Comment: I'm writing a PHP framework. One of my function is doing the above thing. I can query and then code some PHP to have my desire result. But I hope that there is a shorter way to do it.

Comment: @QuiNguyen: If you're writing a framework, then providing functionality as specific as this should be the last thing on your mind. Honestly: a _framework_ is just that: a frame, a skeleton on which people can build. Either way, for the DB component, why not simply use the most mature, well known and most commonly adopted abstraction layer: Doctrine?

Answer (score 3):

Erm, as [the manual clearly states](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php): the results are grouped by the values of the *first* column, so just change:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
```

to

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT colour, name FROM fruit");
```

cf code example you've copy pasted:

```
/* Group values by the >> FIRST << column */
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP));
```

Passing the column index value can indeed be worth a try, too:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$byName = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
$byColour = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP, 1);
```

Comment: $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP, numIndex); I just found out that. It maybe correct.

Comment: *"columns are zero-indexed"* - as is PHP etc. ;) +1 great feature I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Thanks, but credit where it's due, I added that bit in response to the OP's comment... I would've just swapped the columns in the query :-P

Comment: I'm starting to think whether the OP wants/needs the standard GROUP BY at this point lol - OP just edited the question with what he/she wants, set in **bold**. Should have left my original comment? lol

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP, columnIndex);
$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_GROUP, columnName);
```

I don't know it works or not. Just try it.

Comment: `FETCH_UNIQUE` != `FETCH_GROUP`, and either way: quoting the manual: _"`PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`: Returns the indicated 0-indexed column"_ so `columnName` just is right out

Comment: Then read the manual, `columnName` still isn't an option, though